# onhover div should be appear using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

on hover li div will come I got it. my question is by default first div is displayed.i want to show the first div.
Can anyone suggest me?
Help will be appreciated

```js
$('#menu a').hover(function(e){
     hideContentDivs();
     var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
     $('.main div').eq(tmp_div).show();
  });

function hideContentDivs(){
    $('.main div').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();});
}
hideContentDivs();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li id="link1"><a href="#">Topic One</a></li>
            <li id="link2"><a href="#">Topic Two</a></li>
            <li id="link3"><a href="#">Topic Three</a></li>               
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="page1" class="content">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <p>First section of content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="page2" class="content">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>        
        <p>Second section of content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="page3" class="content">        
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
        <p>Third section of content.</p>
        </div>                 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just add  '$("#page1").show();' to the end of your script as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49421578/6597375)

Comment: @ Deepu Reghunath thanks

Comment: No need to change the code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially hide divs except the first, to ignore the first one you can use jQuery [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child) pseudo-selector with [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector or use [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method.

```
$('.main div:not(:first)').hide();
// or
$('.main div').slice(1).hide();
```

```js
$('#menu a').hover(function(e) {
  hideContentDivs();
  var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
  $('.main div').eq(tmp_div).show();
});

function hideContentDivs() {
  $('.main div').hide();
}

$('.main div:not(:first)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li id="link1"><a href="#">Topic One</a></li>
      <li id="link2"><a href="#">Topic Two</a></li>
      <li id="link3"><a href="#">Topic Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="page1" class="content">
      <h1>Page 1</h1>
      <p>First section of content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" class="content">
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
      <p>Second section of content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="page3" class="content">
      <h1>Page 3</h1>
      <p>Third section of content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can simplify the code as well by chaining [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method.

```js
$('#menu a').hover(function(e) {
  var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
  $('.main div').hide().eq(tmp_div).show();
  // -------------^----
});

$('.main div:not(:first)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li id="link1"><a href="#">Topic One</a></li>
      <li id="link2"><a href="#">Topic Two</a></li>
      <li id="link3"><a href="#">Topic Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="page1" class="content">
      <h1>Page 1</h1>
      <p>First section of content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" class="content">
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
      <p>Second section of content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="page3" class="content">
      <h1>Page 3</h1>
      <p>Third section of content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Although it's better to cache the elements for referring inside the callback.

```js
var $divs =$('.main div');
$('#menu a').hover(function(e) {
  var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
  $divs.hide().eq(tmp_div).show();
});

// select divs except first index
$divs.slice(1).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li id="link1"><a href="#">Topic One</a></li>
      <li id="link2"><a href="#">Topic Two</a></li>
      <li id="link3"><a href="#">Topic Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div id="page1" class="content">
      <h1>Page 1</h1>
      <p>First section of content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" class="content">
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
      <p>Second section of content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="page3" class="content">
      <h1>Page 3</h1>
      <p>Third section of content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add $("#page1").show(); to end . It will show first div as default.

```js
$('#menu a').hover(function(e){
     hideContentDivs();
     var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
     $('.main div').eq(tmp_div).show();
  });

function hideContentDivs(){
    $('.main div').each(function(){
    $(this).hide();});
}
hideContentDivs();
$("#page1").show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li id="link1"><a href="#">Topic One</a></li>
            <li id="link2"><a href="#">Topic Two</a></li>
            <li id="link3"><a href="#">Topic Three</a></li>               
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="page1" class="content">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <p>First section of content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="page2" class="content">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>        
        <p>Second section of content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="page3" class="content">        
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
        <p>Third section of content.</p>
        </div>                 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css style for this.

```js
$('#menu a').hover(function(e){
     hideContentDivs();
     var tmp_div = $(this).parent().index();
     $('.main div').eq(tmp_div).show();
});

function hideContentDivs(){
    $('.main div').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="nav">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li id="link1"><a href="#">Topic One</a></li>
            <li id="link2"><a href="#">Topic Two</a></li>
            <li id="link3"><a href="#">Topic Three</a></li>               
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div id="page1" class="content" style="display: block">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
        <p>First section of content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="page2" class="content" style="display: none">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>        
        <p>Second section of content</p>
        </div>
        <div id="page3" class="content" style="display: none">        
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
        <p>Third section of content.</p>
        </div>                 
    </div>
</div>
```